# SQL Index selection not Returning multiple Results

Tags: sql, sql-server, greatest-n-per-group

I want to know how to obtain the lowest index number / Indno if a record contains multiple references (Lets say we got a contract containing the same metadata, the only difference is the index number), but for several records in the same table.

I used some distinct / Min selections or a combination of the 2 on the Indno selection but was unsuccessful.

This gets the lowest Indno record, but only 1 record, instead of them all :

```
Select MIN(Indno) as LowestIndexes 
from TableName 
where indno matches some criteria in other columns
```

Example :

```
IndNo   Col 1     Col 2     Col 3

1       Peanut    Butter    Jelly
2       Peanut    Butter    Jelly
3       Peanut    Butter    Jelly
4       Milk      Oreo      InfiniteJoy
5       Milk      Oreo      InfiniteJoy
6       I         Love      SQL
7       I         Love      SQL
8       I         Love      SQL
9       I         Love      SQL
10      I         Love      SQL
```

For this set of results i must be able to return only the smallest Index number / Indno of each of those records :

```
1  
4 
6
```

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? You can find plenty of examples here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/greatest-n-per-group+sql

Comment: SQL Server 2008 with 2014 Management studio.

Answer (score 0):

try using group like this

```
SELECT 
    IndNo
FROM
    `test`
WHERE 
     Col1 "your criteria" 
     OR Col2 "your criteria" 
     OR Col3 "your criteria"
GROUP BY Col1 , Col2 , Col3
ORDER BY IndNo ASC
```

Comment: This selects everything, not the lowest indno of every record set.

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this:

```
declare @tmpTable table(IndNo int, Col1 nvarchar(max), Col2 nvarchar(max), Col3 nvarchar(max))

insert into @tmpTable(IndNo, Col1, Col2, Col3)
values (1, 'Peanut', 'Butter', 'Jelly'),
       (2, 'Peanut', 'Butter', 'Jelly'),
       (3, 'Peanut', 'Butter', 'Jelly'),
       (4, 'Milk', 'Oreo', 'InfiniteJoy'),
       (5, 'Milk', 'Oreo', 'InfiniteJoy'),
       (6, 'I', 'Love', 'SQL'),
       (7, 'I', 'Love', 'SQL'),
       (8, 'I', 'Love', 'SQL'),
       (9, 'I', 'Love', 'SQL'),
       (10, 'I', 'Love', 'SQL')


;With cte (IndNo, Col1, Col2, Col3, RowNum)
  as (
      select IndNo, Col1, Col2, Col3, 
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER(partition by Col1 Order by Col1) as RowNum
      from @tmpTable
 )
 select IndNo, Col1, Col2, Col3 
      from cte 
 where RowNum = 1
 order by IndNo
```

You can use `partition by` and `ROW_NUMBER()` function to achieve this.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Group By` to group the records. The SQL query will be something like:

```
select MIN(IndNo) as LowestIndexes
from TableName 
where 'Check for the matching criteria in other columns'
group by Col1, Col2, Col3
order by MIN(IndNo)
```